# Tracking counter in nested for loop

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I'm currently working on a small assignment for school.

I need to print the current station where the train is at the moment and the stations that are left from the list.

I have used a nested `for` loop, but I can't get the inner `for` loop to work properly. Do I need to create a variable with `+=1`?

My code:

```
train_station=['Amsterdam-Central','Amsterdam-Amstel','Utrecht']

for x in train_station:
    print("Current station is: "+x)
    print("Stations to go: ")

    begin=0


    for y in range(begin,3,1):
        print(train_stations[y])
```

My output:

```
Current station is: Amsterdam-Central
Stations to go: 
Amsterdam-Central
Amsterdam-Amstel
Utrecht

Current station is: Amsterdam-Amstel
Stations to go:
Amsterdam-Central
Amsterdam-Amstel
Utrecht

Current station is: Utrecht
Stations to go:
Amsterdam-Central
Amsterdam-Amstel
Utrecht
```

Comment: Hint: you `begin=0` each time in the internal for-loop, that's probably *not* what you want.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548708/for-loop-how-to-take-one-off-every-time-you-pass-over/32548762#32548762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done, you just need to increment `begin` on each iteration.

```
train_station=['Amsterdam-Central','Amsterdam-Amstel','Utrecht']
begin = 0

for x in train_station:
    print("Current station is: "+x)
    print("Stations to go: ")

    begin += 1

    for y in range(begin, 3, 1):
        print(train_station[y])
```

And a more *pythonic* solution:

```
for i, x in enumerate(train_station, 1):
    print("Current station is: "+x)
    print("Stations to go: ")

    for y in train_station[i:]:
        print(y)
```